# which phenomena got used to calculate a function that was never computed by digital hardware

Tags: computability

or wich phenomena have behavior that can be measured and described as a function between natural numbers but seem to be hard to simulate with digital hardware when  the starting conditions are given.

Comment: Can you explain the motivation for this question. Physical phenomena, besides counting, usually work with continuous parameters.

Comment: The exact number of molecules located in a half of an enclosure cannot be computed at a given time to one unit. But it cannot be observed either !